# Integrate my web part in my sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have a web part developped by VS2013 that contain a list, then i want to display this list in my site so i have to integrate my web part into my Sharepoint site , but the web part didn't exist in the availaible web part.
thanks

Comment: How did you "_integrate_" you Web Part into your site? If you installed a WSP did you remember to enable the feature for the Web Part?

Comment: Hi 
thx for youre response, I am beginner at sharepoint and I didn't enable anything, could give me a tutorial or instrcutions how to enable this feature to integrate my web part, i will be thankful

Comment: Since it is a Web Part it will be scoped for SPSite (site collection). Go to __Site settings__ > __Site Collection Administration__ > __Site collection features__, here you should find your feature and you can enable it. The name of your feature is probably something like _Feature1_, you can see the actual name under __"Features"__ in your Visual Studio project

Comment: In fact what i developped is a Sharepoint apps, but i want to integrate it like a web part, is this feature available for apps also ??

Comment: You can't deploy Web Parts in apps, only [Client Web Parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481208(v=office.15).aspx) (please see link) which are a bit different

Comment: no i don't want to deploy web parts in apps, i want to deploy my SP apps in my site then add it like a web part,

Comment: What I meant was that apps does not support Web Parts, only Client Web Parts. Your host site can add Client Web Parts which are just iframes to your app at the app domain. In any case this is getting out of hand, I suggest you read up on the link I posted. Your question is about Web Parts, although you don't have and can't have Web Parts in your app so it is in all essence unrelated to your approach